# What is the best way to match color of 2 walls?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

I want to change color of the blue part of the wall to match with white part. What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you cannot recolorize the original, you have only this 2D image.

Nobody here knows what your "match" mean. I guess it means the same light brown as the lighter areas of the wall.

One approach is to make a careful selection with paths or lasso tools of the areas which need a new color. Masked adjustment layers change the actual color. The quality of the selection used to generate the layer masks to the adjustment layers determine the accuracy.

In the next example the selection is based on color and that's very coarse. But it shows the idea. Acceptably sharp borders need a selection with paths or lasso tools.

[image]

The bottom Hue/Saturation layer desaturates the blue areas. The Curves layer makes them lighter. The top Hue/Saturation layer colorizes the desaturated and lightened blue areas to light brown which is obviously the originally selected ambient light.

This layer constellation makes possible also to select another color than the same as the light wall color.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it.